# Custom fontface showing in tutorial site, but not on mine?

Tags: html, css

I've spent a good amount of time searching for plausible causes for this, ranging from Browser Settings to unicode range.

Basically, I've followed the tutorial from over here: http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/ResponsiveIconGrid/
and I successfully implemented it on my website. The functionality, the styles - everything is in check. Except that in place of the icons, I see rectangles/squares, which is frustrating to say the least.

I am using the exact same browser to view both websites and I can see the icons on codrops just fine. Do you guys/girls have any hints on what might be the issue?

Here is the CSS to add the fonts, it seems to be in check:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'anyoldicon';
    src:url('assets/anyoldicon.eot');
    src:url('assets/anyoldicon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('assets/anyoldicon.woff') format('woff'),
        url('assets/anyoldicon.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('assets/anyoldicon.svg#anyoldicon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    unicode-range: U+00-FFFF;
}
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <span class="cbp-ig-icon cbp-ig-icon-whippy"></span>
        <h3 class="cbp-ig-title">George</h3>
        <span class="cbp-ig-category">Smith</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Anything else I might have missed? I'd rather not show the URL, as it will teach you nothing more, to be honest. Its just as described - same layout, but visible on one website and broken on the other.

Also here is the full CSS corresponding to the icons and the animations of the grid: http://pastebin.com/94UgpN8B I also should mention that this icon font is generated by IcoMoon, if that is any help.

I am using Muse to compile the website, and to be honest icons from other projects haven't worked either. Could it be something from there?

I haven't received any 404 errors in console regarding the assets.

I also tried defining the icons styles separately, so as to remove the possibility of incorrect inheriting of class properties (check out the pastebin CSS), but that didn't work either.

**EDIT**
Here is another .CSS file which corresponds to the other part of this "plugin's" functionality. Its the only other file that has any realtion to this, except a very standard morenizr.js

hxxp://pastebin.com/c7w1LEBf

Comment: Have you uploaded them in the correct path? If yes, have you used `<link>` tag to declare it? If yes, have you cleared your browser cache and checked again? If yes and still not working, then please provide us your live website link.

Comment: Have you tried adding your font in `font-family`? like this `font-family: 'anyoldicon', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;`?? - @user2467698

Comment: No, I'll try that and let you know in a second @NathanLee

Comment: @NathanLee Gave it a go, but it doesn't work. I've updated the main post with some additional info on another .css file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's your folder structure?

Where is your css file placed,is it in a seperate folder?
If the fonts are in "assets/" and css in "assets/css" you need to change the path to 
 `src:url('../assets/anyoldicon.eot');`

Notice the "**../**" infront of the path

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not sure I understand - why would the ../ be necessary?

Comment: Yes, sorry. My folder structure is basically that in the root of the website directory there is a folder called assets and in that folder are all my css files and font files. Not very clean, I know, but I am still testing the website. There are other folders like css and images, but there reside mostly Muse files, which have no relation to the specific issue. Also my html files are in the root as well. Let me know if I can give any additional info.

Comment: If your fonts and css is in same folder remove the "assets/" from the path

Comment: OK, and should I keep the ../ ?

Comment: No.
If font files and css in assets folder,it will be
 `src:url('anyoldicon.eot');`

Comment: OK, I attempted that, but it doesn't fix the issue. My code looks like this:
    @font-face {
 font-family: 'bpicons', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
 src:url('bpicons.eot');
 src:url('bpicons.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('bpicons.woff') format('woff'),
  url('bpicons.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('bpicons.svg#bpicons') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}